# What is the object translating part of a monadic endofunctor?

Tags: functional-programming, category-theory, monad

A monad is an endofunctor $T:C\rightarrow C$ with natural transformations $\eta:id_C\rightarrow T$ and $\mu:T^2\rightarrow T$.

Being natural transformations mean that $$T(f)\circ \eta_A = \eta_B\circ id_C(f)$$ should hold and $$T(f)\circ\mu_A = \mu_B\circ T^2(f)$$ also. These are the algebraic expressions that the defining diagrams of natural transformations commute.

Translating this to the language of functional programming, $\eta$ is `unit`, and a polymorphic one, so $\eta_{nat}$ is the monomorphisation of `unit` to the `nat` type. $\mu$ is `join` in the same sense. The functor $T$ consists of two things: it takes object and morphisms. The latter part is called `map` in functional programming. So the above equations translate to

```
map f o unit = unit o f
```

where, if `f` is `A -> B` then this is

```
map f o unit(A) = unit(B) o f
```

but that is usually handled with a polymorphic type system and the second equation is

```
map f o join = join o map (map f)
```

So, `map` is the morphism-translating part of the endofunctor $T$.

But what is the object-translating part of $T$ in functional programming? Is it the type operator `M` when we write `unit: 'a -> 'a M` ?

Comment: Yes, the action on objects of a monad `M` is precisely `M` itself, mapping `A` to `M A`.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are isomorphic to identity morphisms. So, the object-translating portion of the endofunctor is a subportion of the morphism-translating portion, also carried by `map`.